# How to stop opening React Native app on Link(website link) access or click

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I have a React Native application for both Android and iOS. Along with a React web application. Now temporarily I need to stop opening React Native app upon clicking our web application routing link either in email or chat messages or etc.

Tried doing so by commenting out **RCTLinkingManager** references and **Linking** react native code. But no luck.